# want to convert sql quer to caml

Tags: sharepoint-online, sql

I want to convert my sql query to caml query and my sql query is

sql query:

```
select Room from hotel where (time between starttime="2:30" and endtime="4:00") and (date between startdate="1/2/017" and enddate="3/2/2017")
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at CAML Query Helper, it will build the query for you 
https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a converter or just to convert this query?

You should change column types what you need.

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
      <Gt>
        <FieldRef Name="time" />
        <Value Type="Text">2:30</Value>
      </Gt>
      <And>
        <Le>
          <FieldRef Name="time" />
          <Value Type="Text">4:00</Value>
        </Le>
        <And>
          <Gt>
            <FieldRef Name="date" />
            <Value Type="Text">1/2/017</Value>
          </Gt>
          <Le>
            <FieldRef Name="date" />
            <Value Type="Text">3/2/2017</Value>
          </Le>
        </And>
      </And>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```